# how to delete rows from GreenDao based on condition?

Tags: android, mobile, greendao

i want to delete rows from a table based on condition. like

"delete from Table where Name='Value'"

here i am using greenDAO database.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1 Check the [documentation](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/queries/).

2 Create a DeleteQuery for your Table

3 Execute it

4 Clear the session so that all caches lose the deleted objects too.

```
final DeleteQuery<Table> tableDeleteQuery = daoSession.queryBuilder(Table.class)
.where(TableDao.Properties.Name.eq("Value"))
.buildDelete();
tableDeleteQuery.executeDeleteWithoutDetachingEntities();
daoSession.clear();
```

If you need to execute the query multiple times, save the query object to avoid re-instantiating it.

Btw greenDAO is an ORM, not a database (here it's SQLite).